# How to download the latest version of youtube-dl programmatically?

Tags: curl, synology, youtube-dl

The latest version of `youtube-dl` is at:

https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/

which redirects to (as of today):

https://yt-dl.org/downloads/2015.07.04/

I'd like to set up a cron job to download the latest version automatically into my Synology box, like:

```
curl https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -o /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

but the above returns:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://yt-dl.org/downloads/2015.07.04/youtube-dl">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at yt-dl.org Port 443</address>
</body></html>
```

So, how can I download the latest verision of `youtube-dl` programmatically from the *latest* path?

Comment: Generally, these sort of problems can be worked around by using lynx to download the file instead of curl (lynx is a full featured browser so it will handle the redirect just fine). I'm fairly sure it'll work but I'm too lazy to test it right now so I'll just leave this comment. Also, you'l probably want to parse the resulting page to find the latest link.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out `youtube-dl` comes with a update function:

```
youtube-dl -U
```